# array of char * converted to char *

Tags: c, string, pointers

How to retrieve the data from domain_cx in domaine , once I'm in the function get_domaine(...) I have tried the following, but the result isnt what expected (0-2 instead of 0-2 3). Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_domaine(char * domaine)
{
  char (*ptr_dom)[10];
  ptr_dom = (char (*)[10]) domaine;
  printf("%s ", ptr_dom[0]); // will print
  printf("%s ", ptr_dom[1]); // will not print even thought there is data.
  return 1;
}

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
   char *domaine_cx[10];

   domaine_cx[0] = "0-2";
   domaine_cx[1] = "3";

  if(get_domaine((char *)*domaine_cx)) printf("Ok");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I edited it, it does compile now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to cast `char (*) [10]` to `char *` just so that you can try to cast it back afterwards. Much simpler would be changing the prototype of your function instead:

```
int get_domaine(char* domaine[10])
{
    printf("%s ", domaine[0]);
    printf("%s ", domaine[1]);
    return 1;
}
```

and in `main`:

```
if (get_domaine(domaine_cx))
    printf("Ok");
```

Alternatively you might not pass an array of any size and pass the size in other argument explicitly:

```
int get_domaine(char* domaine[], int tokens)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < tokens; ++i)
        printf("%s ", domaine[i]);
    return 1;
}
```

and in `main`:

```
if (get_domaine(domaine_cx, 2))
    printf("Ok");
```

---

And in case you really can not change the prototype, than this evil cast would do:

```
int get_domaine(char* domaine)
{
    char** myEvilPtr = (char**) domaine;       // !!! we don't know the size !!!
    printf("%s ", myEvilPtr[0]);
    printf("%s ", myEvilPtr[1]);
    return 1;
}
```

and since arrays decay into pointers, in main you could still do simple:

```
if (get_domaine(domaine_cx))
    printf("Ok");
```

Comment: try function declaration int **get_domaine(char* domaine[])**, or get_domaine(char** domaine)

Comment: I have no control over the signature, unfortunately

Comment: Since i know the size of the array of char* I can cast it to a pointer to a char (the first char) , knowing the size , can't I use it from that pointer to a char ?

Comment: @user2827260: As far as I'm aware, there are no guarantees that a `char *` will be the same size as a `char **`, although on most systems you'll encounter that will be the case. As such, anything you can do will probably be undefined behavior.

Comment: @user2827260: In that case see my edit (under line), however I do not give you any guarantees regarding that approach. The last mentioned solution is provided AS IS and you use it on your own risk :D :D

Comment: @icktoofay: A pointer is a pointer is a pointer. It doesn't matter whether the pointer points to a char, a double, or an array of something...

Comment: @elgonzo: You can't cast pointers around willy-nilly. You can cast a pointer to something to a pointer to `char`, a pointer to `void`, back to whatever it originally was pointing to, and, as far as I know, nothing else without triggering undefined behavior. Furthermore, as far as I know, the standard gives no guarantees to sizes of pointers beyond that a `void *` is big enough to hold any other pointer.

Comment: Although because you are allowed to cast any pointer to a pointer-to-`char` and back, in this particular instance it's probably *not* undefined behavior. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @icktoofay: Sorry, i got you wrong, because you spoke of the size of the pointer depending on the type it points to, which is not the case. Of course, you are right that you can't cast pointers arbitrarily -- well you could, if you like your program to crash :) (But i see that my response was ambiguous, too)

Comment: So the best course would be to parse the strings in the array of pointer to char* and pass this new char * variable